# WPF: Perform tasks when an Application Loads

Tags: wpf, vb.net, file, startup, visual-studio-2015

I feel like I should have been able to find this, but I am struggling. I'm fairly new to this. Here's what I'm looking to do:

I am creating a WPF application using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2015. When the application starts, I would like for it to search for specific files/folders and check if they are there. If not, I would like it to create those files. For example, I want to check and see if the file `%appdata%\RRB\Items.txt` is on the users' computer. If it isn't, I want it to create it.
If it is, wonderful! Leave it there.

I know how to create directories and the files. What I'm struggling with is how to get it to run the check when the application starts. Is there a Sub or Function that specifically runs code when the application starts up?

I did a quick check, and I was unable to find this question on here, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: In the App.xaml file there are an event startup (or similar) for the Application control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to Override *OnStartup*. It is in *App.Xaml.cs* file.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Another option is in *MainWindow* constructor. See *App.Xaml* to check which Window is the Main. It should be something like this:

```
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
```

If so, you can set your code before (or after) *InitializeComponent()* in this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();              
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to use code after InitializeComponent(); Thank you for your help on this!